# Post large JSON object using ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, wildfly

I need help with posting large JSON object to server using ajax in angularjs. When I send JSON object with around 10000 records in an `ArrayList` using post request,It gets accepted and I get the response for the same.But when I upload 30000 records or more and try to send it using ajax, it returns following error :-

```
[io.undertow.request] (default task-5) UT005007: Request was not fully consumed
```

How can I fix this?

I am using Wildfly 10 and java 8. Is there any post size parameter I can increase?

Comment: It seems it the max limit set with your server for file upload.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using [Undertow](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html) for receiving the POST request. Check what is the value of the `MAX_ENTITY_SIZE` option in your setup, perhaps it was limited:

> The default maximum size of a request entity. If entity body is larger than this limit then a `java.io.IOException` will be thrown at some point when reading the request (on the first read for fixed length requests, when too much data has been read for chunked requests). This value is only the default size, it is possible for a handler to override this for an individual request by calling `io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.setMaxEntitySize(long size)`. Defaults to unlimited.

As suggested in [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/252840) this is potentially configured in Spring using `MultipartConfigFactory` bean:

```
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
     MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
     factory.setMaxFileSize("100MB");
     factory.setMaxRequestSize("100MB");
     return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion @KarolDowbecki made will likely work but there is another way too.  In the `standalone.xml` file you're using, you can change from:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
```

to:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" max-post-size="16777216"/>
```

to increase, in this case, to 16MB.  The default is 10MB on at least Wildfly 16.

Alternatively, if you want to script this so that you don't have to manually modify `standalone.xml` you can use the jboss-cli and run:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default/:write-attribute(name=max-post-size,value=16777216)
```